# use of 'by account'

Tags: grammar, writing-style

Does this sentence make sense? Does it suit an academic writing style?

*The equilibrium change in global temperature realised by account of a doubling of atmospheric carbon dioxide.*

Thanks.

Comment: In a word, no. ... But proofreading requests are off-topic here; if you have a specific issue to ask about we can address that.

Comment: Really? What part doesn't make sense?

Comment: Maybe you mean the average changed as a result of a doubling...

Comment: I feel like this questioner is trying to get a better grasp of English in order to write more goodly.  Jisu's proposed correction greatly clarifies the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @DukeZhou 'more goodly'? I winced :D

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence isn't a sentence - you don't have a main verb. "By account of" doesn't make sense either.

You would have to say "...change is accounted for by.."